# Drop filter not working logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have multiple log messages in a file which I am processing using logstash filter plugins. Then, the filtered logs are getting sent to elasticsearch.

There is one field called **addID** in a log message. I want to drop all the log messages which have a particular addID present. These particular addIDS are present in a ID.yml file.

Scenario: If the addID of a log message matches with any of the addIDs present in the ID.yml file, that log message should be dropped.

Could anyone help me in achieving this?

Below is my config file.

```
input {


    file {
     path => "/Users/jshaw/logs/access_logs.logs
     ignore_older => 0
    }
}

filter {


    grok {

        patterns_dir => ["/Users/jshaw/patterns"]
        match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP:Timestamp}+{IP:ClientIP}+{URI:Uri}"]

    }


    kv{
        field_split => "&?"
      include_keys => [ "addID" ]
      allow_duplicate_values => "false"

    }

    if [addID] in "/Users/jshaw/addID.yml" {
        drop{}
    }

}

output {

     elasticsearch{
       hosts => ["localhost:9200"]

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `in` operator wrong. It is used to check if a value is in an array, not in a file, which are usually a bit more complicated to use.

A solution would be to use the ruby filter to open the file each time.
Or put the addId value in your configuration file, like this:

```
if [addID] == "addID" {
    drop{}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
So, if I use ruby filter then would I be able to drop log messages which have a particular addID??

Comment: @User24 Yes. Cf [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html)